# Generate Certificate (award)

Tags: .net, documentation-generator

I need to generate A4 letter/certificate/award online that can be printed by users that works on all devices. It has to look nice and allow me to dynamically add text to it.

Currently I have a .NET website that inserts text dynamically into a PDF template. However if the user has different versions of Adobe reader or is using another PDF reader the PDF does not display the dynamic text correctly.

Is there a online site? Library? or any free/cheap solution to generate a nice looking awards that I can insert text into at runtime.

Or is my best option to use HTML + CSS?

Answer (score 2):

[Syncfusion Essential PDF Viewer for ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/aspnetmvc/pdf-viewer) is an option to consider. This will allow you to display the generated PDF in a consistent manner irrespective of the PDF Viewer the user has.

[Online sample browser](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/pdfviewer/default.aspx)

[image: Syncfusion ASP.NET PDF Viewer]

It will also be helpful to review how you are generating the PDF as that might be the cause for the PDF not being displayed properly in different viewers. Syncfusion also provides a [PDF](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/pdf/helloworld.aspx) library in case you want to try using that to generate the PDFs.

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=screcs40064) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use HTML + CSS and generate a web page and then write that web page in-memory to PDF. That will give you more control to make small adjustments.